# What are the supported TLDs for AWS Certificate Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, tld

Just trying to setup either a wildcard `*.mydomain.nz` or `mydomain.nz`, but resulting in `Invalid public domain` failed status.

Their [learn more](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#failed-invalid-domain) link doesn't hint at what TLDs are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the page you linked to:

> If you continue to receive this failure reason, use the [Support Center](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support)
>   to contact AWS Support. If you don't have a support plan, post a new
>   thread in the [AWS Certificate Manager discussion forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=206).